# jQuery how to loop a function after a series of delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, delay

I have a function which has a series of several delayed functions:

```
function greet(t) {
    $("div").delay(t*2).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Bonjour");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*3).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Hola");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*4).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Hallo");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*5).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("Hello"); // back to original
        n();
    });
}

greet(500);
```

With a simple `<div>Hello</div>` in HTML. This way, the greeting changes language every 500ms.

After the function completes (which takes about 2 seconds; 2000ms) I want to start the function over and have loop it infinitely. So, I tried the usual:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
       greet(500);
    }, 2500); // after 2500ms, repeat the function
```

If you notice, once it loops through twice, it stops at "Hello". Why is this? Here is a fiddle displaying my problem http://jsfiddle.net/rgX6B/2/

Any help would be much appreciated!

### Edit:

I actually simplified my problem for the sake of asking a question. I didn't want to post a big wall of code (the changing of the inner html are actually complex functions that involve changing the positioning of CSS shapes.) My problem was ultimately solved by putting the `setTimeout` *inside* the function. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Your greeting doesn't change every 500ms. The first is after 1000ms, the second is 1500ms after that, the next is 2000ms later, and so on. You're using `.queue()` but also increasing the duration between each. If you want every 500ms, then get rid of the multiplication.

Comment: ...and to solve your issue, you don't need `setTimeout()` at all. Just put `greet(500)` in the last callback after the `n();`. http://jsfiddle.net/rgX6B/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use it in your function

http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/rgX6B/4/

```
function greet(t) {
    $("div").delay(t*1).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Bonjour");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*2).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Hola");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*3).queue(function(n) {
         $(this).html("Hallo");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*4).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).html("Hello"); // back to original
        n();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
       greet(500);
    }, 500);
}

greet(500);
```

another solution would be to use `setInterval(function() { greet(..) }, 3000);`

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm seems a bit messy, and violates DRY, making it more difficult to maintain. Here's an alternative:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLQXj/

```
var greetings = [
    "Hello",
    "Bonjour",
    "Hola",
    "Hallo"
];

function greet(idx) {
    $('div').html(greetings[idx]);
    var next = (idx + 1) > (greetings.length - 1) ? 0 : idx + 1;
    setTimeout(function() { greet(next); }, 1000);
}

greet(0);
```

Comment: I would use this, but I actually simplified what I really have for the sake of asking the question. I know that when people post big walls of code it deters answerers from answering. I cannot adapt what I really have to this. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 2):

> *"If you notice, once it loops through twice, it stops at "Hello". Why is this?"*

The `setTimeout()` method queues up a function to be executed *once* after a given delay, so you would need to call it from inside your function if you want it to keep repeating - or use `setInterval()` instead.

However, you are misusing the `.delay()` method, which is really intended to be used with [other jQuery animation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). `setTimeout()` is what you should be using for all of the delays in your function. I'd probably implement your function more like this:

```
function greet(delay, messages, nextMessage) {
    if (nextMessage === undefined) nextMessage = 0;
    $("div").html(messages[nextMessage]);
    setTimeout(function() {
        greet(delay, messages, (nextMessage + 1) % messages.length);
    }, delay);
}

greet(500, ["Hello","Hola","Hallo"]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgX6B/5/

You could perhaps add another parameter to indicate which element(s) to set the `.html()` for, rather than hardcoding that in the function...

Comment: I would use this, but I actually simplified what I really have for the sake of asking the question. I know that when people post big walls of code it deters answerers from answering. I cannot adapt what I really have to this. Thanks for the answer though!